# Best strategy to block concurrent button presses. Block spacebar while holding CTRL

Tags: keyboard, script, autohotkey, ctrl

So a few weeks ago I modified my mechanical keyboard to lube the switches, I broke the Left-ctrl key's contacts on the pcb making it a dummy switch. I have since ran jumpers from the left-ctrl to the right-ctrl contacts.

However I am now getting some strange interactions where every time I press the ctrl keys it also activates the space bar. (No the wires do not contact the space bar contacts in any way)

The main question is, how do I go about disabling the spacebar when I press the ctrl key? This is an issue when I'm programming and highlight a section to copy or paste to, and all of a sudden a spacebar input overwrites what I am doing. I'm open to any strange methods or use of Autohotkey. Or if you have any other suggestions on how to mitigate this using hardware, I am open to this. The keyboard is a HyperX mechanical TKL if that helps.

Comment: Buy a new keyboard

Answer (score 1):

AutoHotkey will allow you to disable Ctrl+Space if that's what you're asking... use the default script when it installs or create a new one, and add this:

```
#Persistent
^Space::Return
```